# How to display custom widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a problem in my Flutter app with implement my custom Widget LifeViewList(). When I try do it createState()_HomePageState need some arguments, when I do it then I get a worrnig “Don’t put any logic in createState” .

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomePage(
{ Key? key,
  required this.user, 
}) : super(key: key);
final User user;

@override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
late ScrollController _scrollController;
double _scrollControllerOffset = 0.0;

_HomePageState(this.lifeView);

void _scrollListener() {
setState(() {
  _scrollControllerOffset = _scrollController.offset;
});
}

 @override
 void initState() {
 _scrollController = ScrollController();
 _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
 super.initState();
 }
 final LifeView lifeView;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          const LogoBanner(),
          const Topic('How do you feel today?'),
          const EmotionGrid(),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(height: 20),
          ),
          const Topic('A place to think about yourself.'),
          LifeViewList(
            LifeView(
              title: lifeView.title,
              image: lifeView.image,
              id:lifeView.id,
            ),
          ),
          const SingOutButton(),
        ],
      ),
      FadeAppBar(scrollOffset: _scrollControllerOffset)
    ],
  ),
  );
  }
  }
```

What I have to change ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the code _as text_, not as an image

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To access your widget variables in your state you can do `widget.variable` within your state class.

For example using `user`:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({ Key? key, required this.user,}) : super(key: key);
  final User user;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.user.username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do this I have to use this parameter in my RootPage(). and next I have to send this to MyApp().  I would like to not do this.

Comment: @JarosławGawlik learn Provider then